# php mysql where clause using Date

Tags: php, mysql, time, where-clause, sql-update

Can anyone help me with the following?

```
$crDate = date("Y-m-d");
$sql="update callrecord set crEndtime = Now() where crUsId = ".$crUsId."AND crDate = ".$crDate;
```

What I'm trying to do is update a table **"callrecord"** where the `crDate` is current date. when I take the And part out, it works fine.

```
$sql="update callrecord set crEndtime = Now() where crUsId = ".$crUsId;
```

this works fine. But I want to check with current **date** too. any help?

Comment: You usually enter a Date as a string so you would need to quote it. For example `SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate='2008-11-11';` [Source](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_dates.asp) here. A datetime would be '2008-11-11 03:29:12';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MySQL function `curdate()` without calculating it within php.

```
$sql = "update callrecord set crEndtime = Now() 
        where crUsId = '$crUsId' AND crDate = curdate()";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using single quotes arround the $crDate.